# How to Deploy an artifact programmatically using Maven

Tags: maven, devops, maven-embedder

I have a mission to develop an integration tool which allows from a source code folder to generate a WAR or OSGI Bundle and then deploys it in Tomcat or Karaf. I used Maven Embedder to create the artifacts, now my problem is how to configure my pom.xml to automatically deploy these artifacts.

on the internet I can't find any examples and also I'm new to the world of JEE and Maven.
please help me.

Comment: I wonder why you develop an integration tool. Why not use something that is already there?

Comment: What I'm really doing is developing a compiler that will take a DSL file as input and then generate an executable like jar or war and deploy this executable automatically.How existing solutions can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: You could write a Maven plugin that transforms your DSL to Java sources or compiles them directly and then use it in the POM. Then you can call Maven to do the rest.

Comment: If you are in JEE I would use Maven to create an WAR/EAR file and deploying is a job for something different ......

Answer (score 2):

1. Find out how you can deploy artifacts to Tomcat or Karaf (without Maven).
2. Find out how you can deploy artifacts to Tomcat or Karaf programmatically.
3. Find a Maven plugin to use that deployment method.

The simplest solution would be to use something like the `maven-resources-plugin` to copy your built artifacts to the servers deployment directory but I am pretty sure that there are more sophisticated methods like http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/tomcat7-maven-plugin/deploy-only-mojo.html for deploying out of maven without plain file system mechanisms.

On a wider scale when working on problems like yours it always helps to take a step back and think about the abstract use case ("How to deploy something somewhere" followed by "How to deploy something somewhere programmatically") before going into detail and think about Tomcat or other application servers - and in most cases you will find out that there were hundreds of other who already had the same problem and solved it some way or the other.